# Алгоритм золотой середины?

Tags: математика, алгоритм

Реализация программы для кропа изображений привела меня в тупик. Не могу выявить закономерность при создании такого алгоритма:

Даны  х,у . Найти такие минимальные dx и dy, чтобы (x - dx)/(y - dy) = 3/2

Т.е. в результате два новых числа будут относиться как 3:2.(Впрочем соотношение может быть любым).

Пример:

- 1500 и 1100  - на выходе 1500 и 1000 (dx=0, dy=100)
- 1500 и 1300 - на выходе 1200 и 800 (dx=300,dy=500)

Интутитивно я какбы догадываюсь, но описать алгоритмом не могу. Кто знает, подскажите хотя бы ход мыслей!

Comment: Самый тупой способ - перебирать в цикле dx и dy от 0 до какого-то макс значения, пока не найдете нужные значения... Понятно, что резать изображение до величины (0;0) не надо.

Comment: Не очень понятно, что значит "минимальные dx и dy". Понятно, когда минимизируется один параметр, но два? Например, какие значения "меньше": (1, 100) или (10, 10) ?  

Кстати, почему в последнем случае такой ответ? Можно взять dx = 0, dy = 300, дробь примет вид 1500/1000

Можно ли брать приращения dx, dy отрицательными?

Comment: @gecube, ну это и был мой изначально придуманный способ. Конечно, для фото вариантов не так уж много,можно перебрать.Но  интересно было бы узнать общий алгоритм, когда х и у могут быть совершенно разными.

Comment: @neofit, мне тоже это не очень ясно, но скорее всего подразумевалось, что площадь полученеого изображения должна быть максимальна.

Comment: Насчет минимальности я поняла. Если dx и dy положительны (неотрицательны), то среди них есть минимальные. Кроме того, чем больше dx, тем больше dy, так что минимизируя одно, минимизируем и другое. Достаточно проверить минимальное dx(будет ли dy >=0) и наименьшее dy (будет ли dx >=0). Видимо, выполняется только одно из условий.

Comment: Я думаю, задачу лучше переформулировать так: найти наибольший прямоугольник с отношением сторон 3:2, помещающийся строго внутри данного. Так условие будет корректным.

Comment: @VladD, так и есть.

Comment: @gecube, ресайзить нельзя, т.к. при ресайзе сохраняются исходные пропорции.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

самый простой вариант:

```
public class TestCrop
{
    private static final double DIMENSION_REL = 1.5;

    public int x;
    public int y;

    public TestCrop ( int x, int y )
    {
        setX ( x );
        setY ( y );
    }

    public static void main ( String [] args )
    {
        test ( new TestCrop ( 1500, 1100 ) );
        test ( new TestCrop ( 1500, 1300 ) );
        test ( new TestCrop ( 1600, 1100 ) );
        test ( new TestCrop ( 1600, 1300 ) );
        test ( new TestCrop ( 1700, 1100 ) );
        test ( new TestCrop ( 1700, 1300 ) );
    }

    private static void test ( TestCrop point )
    {
        System.out.println ( "in   = " + point );
        TestCrop result = calc ( point );
        System.out.println ( "out  = " + result );
        System.out.println ();
    }

    private static TestCrop calc ( TestCrop p )
    {
        double rel = (double) p.getX () / p.getY ();
        if ( rel > DIMENSION_REL ) {
            return new TestCrop ( (int) ( p.getY () * DIMENSION_REL ), p.getY () );
        }

        return new TestCrop ( p.getX (), (int) ( p.getX () / DIMENSION_REL ) );
    }

    // методы get/set

    @Override
    public String toString ()
    {
        return String.format ( "{%d, %d}", getX (), getY () );
    }
}
```

на выходе:

```
in   = {1500, 1100}
out  = {1500, 1000}

in   = {1500, 1300}
out  = {1500, 1000}

in   = {1600, 1100}
out  = {1600, 1066}

in   = {1600, 1300}
out  = {1600, 1066}

in   = {1700, 1100}
out  = {1650, 1100}

in   = {1700, 1300}
out  = {1700, 1133}
```

более сложный:

Задача найди размеры изображения которые будут максимально близки к исходным, это значит что у них должны быть минимальные `{dx, dy}`, что так же означает что `dx*dy` должно стремится к `x*y`. Если обозначить результаты которые возвращает простая реализация как `{rx, ry}`, то более точным решением будет рекурсия с подсчетом `dx*dy` где значения находятся в диапазонах: `[rx; x]` для `dx` и `[ry; y]` для `dy`. Для каждой проверенной пары `{dx, dy}` надо вызвать проверку для `{dx-1, dy}` и `{dx, dy-1}`

p.s. поиск будет идти по спаданию значений т.к. нас интересует макс. значения размеров

p.s.s не думаю, что в данной ситуации есть смысл настолько увиличивать сложность алгоритма

Comment: Алгоритм нечестный. Объясняю. Тут идет округление. Т.е. может получиться ситуация, что по вертикали 1000, а по горизонтали - 666 пикселов. Мне кажется, что подразумевалось, что на выходе должны быть целые числа, которые находятся в точно указанных пропорциях, но все плюс за попытку.

Comment: Благодарю! Это java? Переведем на php! По словарю)))

Comment: @jmu, несмотря на некорректно заданный вопрос вы ИНТУИТИВНО поняли,что я имел в виду

Comment: @gecube, я думаю, для обрезки фотографий доли пикселов не важны, все округляется и обрезается. Я так думаю.

Comment: @Deus, лучше уточнить! Просто принципиально те же приемы применимы не только к обрезке, но и масштабированию изображений. И тогда придется считать каждый пиксель как какую-то среднюю сумму пикселов исходного изображения. И это проще сделать, если изображение меняется в строго определенных пропорциях....

Comment: @gecube, может я и ошибаюсь, но вопрос возник из-за того, что иногда нужно из произвольного изображения получить изображение например строго 150х100, сжатием и обычным ресайзом этого не добиться. Поэтому  у изображения НУЖНО обрезать стороны подгоняя их под заданную пропорцию, так чтобы в результате получилось изображение  более-менее соответстующее реальному.

Comment: @Deus, задачи разные есть. Ну, например, Ваша такова - есть фотография человека. Нужно из этой фотографии подготовить фото на какой-либо документ. При этом пропорции, понятное дело, менять нельзя. Т.е. нельзя искажать оригинал. Обрезать - можно. Ресайзить (в пропорции одновременно высоту и ширину) - в принципе тоже. А на каждый документ существуют определенные критерии к фотографиям. Скажем, размеры 4х3, 5х4 и пр. Вот и получается, что все равно нужно будет выяснить сколько пикселов займет выходное изображение (ширина и длина прямоугольника)

Answer (score 4):

Возьмем вместо 3/2 дробь a/b. Уравнение, приведенное в вопросе, можно привести к виду ady - bdx = ay - bx = const. Это известное диофантово уравнение.
Если найдено частное решение dx = u, dy = v, общее решение будет иметь вид dx = u + bn, dx = v - an для любого целого n.

Соответственно, есть решение, у которого dx - наименьшее положительное из всех. Также есть решение с наименьшим положительным dy.

Например, для x = 1600, y = 1200, a = 3, b = 2 получаем  3dx - 2dy = 700. Достаточно взять dy четным числом, dx = 2k получим, что dy = 3k - 350. Наименьшее dx будет 0, тогда dy = -350. Наименьшее положительное dy будет dy = 1 (при k = 117), тогда dx = 234.

Если допустить и отрицательные dx, dy, можно найти и меньшие по модулю значения. Например, при k = 70 имеем dx = 140, dy = -140.

В математике есть алгоритм решения такого рода уравнений, алгоритм Евклида. Но, думаю, проще организовать прямой перебор, если числа не очень большие.